# How do I set the BRANCH Flow Service to execute the TRUE and FALSE branches?

Tags: webmethods

How can I get the BRANCH statement in the following flow service screen shot to execute the TRUE and FALSE branches?

I have the Switch set to the variable that I want: /LowerCase I set the Scope to lowercase "doug" and my MAP above the BRANCH is a LowerCase string.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value of the /LowerCase field in your pipeline is "doug" then you should simply add a sub-sequence with label "doug"

[image]

Comment: Nice, so on the if part you just have to have the label the value that you want to use in the if statement what about an else would that just be another SEQUENCE with a $default label or $null label. Could you if you have time post an example of and if-else statement if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For the same question, Branch can be used in two ways in the image below:

[image]

- Method 1:  Use branch like a switch-case statement (The first branch statement)
- Method 2:  Use branch like an if-else statement  (The second branch statement)

Hope it helps!!